# Filtering data from Excel

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dictionary, for-loop

I'm trying to create first version of working program that would read through data from excel and filter those numbers. My sensor is faulty so sometimes jumps to very high numbers.

I've managed to read files and code filters numbers but problem is I have to run last few lines of code twice. On first try nothing happens.

Can somebody explain or help with example what I'm doing wrong? I guess I'm trying to delete number I'm iterating over, but I don't know how to work around it. Maybe somehow when converting to dict if I can sort those numbers?)

EDIT:

[picture of folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYcVp.png)

[Data in Excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpFp9.png)

For school, I'm trying to read through multiple Excel data, take values from first 3 columns. In second column is data of path traveled, which shows faulty values. I want to find those faulty values and remove those values and values of Force and time associated with them (as per screenshot[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpFp9.png) I'm trying to remove all data from first rows).

I'll use those data in further graph drawings and approximations and some calculations, but first I need to have list of data that is ok.

Thank you!

```
i = 1
rotorji = {} #open empty dic
rotor = {} #open empty dic
if rotorji is {}:
    rotorji.clear()
else:
     rotorji = {} #if i forget to clear dic

for file in os.listdir():
   if file.endswith(".xlsx"):
       rotorji[i] = {}
       rotor[i] = {}
       rotorji[i] = pd.read_excel(file, usecols=(0, 1, 2), names = ('Time','Path','Force'))
       rotor[i] = rotorji[i].to_dict('list')
       i = i+1


try:
    del i
except NameError:
    pass
try:
    del j
except NameError:
    pass

try:
    del v
except NameError: #celaring variables
    pass

for i in rotor:
    for v in rotor[i]['Path']: #for value in dictionari of key path
        if v < 0.0 or v > 400.0 :
            rotor[i]['Force'].pop(rotor[i]['Path'].index(v))
            rotor[i]['Time'].pop(rotor[i]['Path'].index(v))
            rotor[i]['Path'].pop(rotor[i]['Path'].index(v))
```

Comment: Please explain better what are you trying to do after loading the files. also show the structure of your data

Comment: @gtomer Thank you for comment, I've edited the question with added pictures. Hopefuly I've managed to explain better what I'm trying to do

Comment: You are trying to filter out above a certain threshold?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right, you want to filter out above a certain threshold values in your 'Untitled 1' column.
If this is the case and you have all your data in a dataframe, this will do the job:

```
threshold = 1000
df = df[df['Untitled 1'] < threshold]
```